# Can I use printf in an Android native binary

Tags: c, android-ndk, adb, console-application, arm64

Let's assume the phone is rooted and arm binaries can be installed. Can I make a console binary using Android Studio with `printf` output?

Is there a step-by-step guide to writing and compiling such binaries with a traditional C Program `int main()` with Android Studio or creation of the `Android.mk` file

There are some projects on GitHub doing this:

https://github.com/strazzere/android-unpacker/tree/master/native-unpacker

And

https://github.com/Shabbypenguin/DexPwn

Comment: Since NDK r19 all versions are by default "stand-alone toolchains" that means they can be used like any other gcc installation for cros-compiling. So you don't need to do anything Android specific https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain

Comment: for printf to do anything useful you need a text console running a shell to launch the program, like termux.

Comment: @stark ADB on PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Hello, world\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Then:

1. `~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/24.0.8215888/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang --target=aarch64-linux-android21 helloworld.c -o helloworld`
2. `adb push helloworld /data/local/tmp/helloworld`
3. `adb shell /data/local/tmp/helloworld`

Comment: Need to put anything inside `Android.mk`?

Comment: Not really. This isn't a "normal" Android app, so I just gave the raw commands you would use to compile it.

Comment: Then what happens if you need to use 3rd party libraries? Surely there should be a neat way to do it from Android Studio like a console app wizard, although it should be reminded rooting is unsupported

Comment: Command-line executables are not really a supported use case for the NDK. You can do it, there's nothing about the compiler that prevents it, but it's unlikely it would ever be supported in Android Studio, which is intended for regular Android app development.